# Changing/Creating Windows registry.pol using Rust

Tags: windows, rust

I'm trying to edit registry.pol file.
, but I do not know how to save changes.

I used crate registry-pol (https://docs.rs/registry-pol/1.0.0/registry_pol/v1/fn.parse.html) to read content of the current file.

```
let mut f = File::open("c:\\windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\machine\\registry.pol").unwrap();
let mut buffer = Vec::new();
f.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
let mut x = registry_pol::v1::parse(&buffer).unwrap();
let value: u32 = 1;
let bytes = value.to_le_bytes();
x.push(registry_pol::v1::RegistryValue {
    key: "any key".to_string(),
    value: Some("any value".to_string()),
    data_type: Some(registry_pol::v1::RegistryValueType::REG_DWORD),
    data: Some(bytes.to_vec()),
});
```

But if I add anything to Vec I do not have a clue how to save it as new registry.pol file.
Thanks